Проблема с прозрачностью видео VP8 в Unity для Android
Я использую Unity для создания приложения, которое отображает видео из URL. Видео имеет формат webm с кодеком VP8. В редакторе Unity все работает как ожидается - видео отображается с прозрачным фоном. Однако, при сборке проекта под Android, прозрачность пропадает, и видео отображается с непрозрачным фоном.
Вот участок моего кода:
[SerializeField] private RawImage _rawImage;
[SerializeField] private UnityEngine.Video.VideoPlayer _videoPlayer;

private void Start()
{
    string pathToSaveVideo;

    if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
    {
        pathToSaveVideo = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "12.webm");
    }
    else if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer)
    {
        pathToSaveVideo = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "12.webm");
    }
    else
    {
        pathToSaveVideo = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "12.webm");
    }
    _videoPlayer.url = pathToSaveVideo;
    _videoPlayer.Prepare();
    _videoPlayer.prepareCompleted += (videoPlayer) =>
    {
        _videoPlayer.Play();
    };
}

